# How I can add class attribute in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, websocket

I want to make a class that tranmit a data from websocket to udp socket.
This code uses [simple-websocket-server](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server) module to implement websocket server.
So I am trying to add udp socket as a class attribute but it raise a error.
How I can fix it?

Note that I know that This error is able to avoid using closure when DataWebSocket Object pass to SimpleSSLWebSocketServer.
But I want to try to class-embed udp socket and I want to learn about class attribute in python.

This is code:

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import WebSocket, SimpleSSLWebSocketServer, SimpleWebSocketServer
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import ssl
import signal
import sys
import socket
import os.path
import traceback

class DataWebSocket(WebSocket):
    def __new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        try:
            super().__new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
            cls.udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # add udp socket as a class attribute (not instance attribute)
            cls.udp_sock.setblocking(False)
            cls.udp_sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 6666))
            print("cls")
            return cls
        except:
            t, mes, tb = sys.exc_info()
            print(traceback.format_exception(t, mes, tb))
            return cls
    def __init__(self, server, sock, address):
        try:
            super().__init__(server, sock, address)
        except:
            t, mes, tb = sys.exc_info()
            print(traceback.format_exception(t, mes, tb))
    def handleMessage(self):
        try:
            if isinstance(self.data, str):
                data = self.data.encode("utf-8")
            else:
                data = self.data
            self.udp_sock.sendto(data, ("127.0.0.1", 7774))
            print("raw_data is:", self.data)
        except Exception as e:
            t, mes, tb = sys.exc_info()
            print(traceback.format_exception(t, mes, tb)) # just print error for keep it execute server.;

    def handleClose(self):
        print("connection: closed " + self.address)
        self.sendMessage("server exit")
        #sys.exit()

    def handleConnected(self):
        print("Connected", self.address)


def start_data_receiver():
    #udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    #udp_sock.setblocking(False)
    #udp_sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 6666))
    SSL = True
    if SSL:
        server = SimpleSSLWebSocketServer("localhost", 4246, DataWebSocket, "../certs/localhost.crt", "../certs/localhost.key.pem")
    else:
        server = SimpleWebSocketServer("localhost", 4246, DataWebSocket)
    print("start server: 127.0.0.1:4246")
    server.serveforever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_data_receiver()
```

This is Error print:

```
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "data_receiver_ws2.py", line 26, in __new__\n    super().__new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)\n', 'TypeError: object() takes no parameters\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_receiver_ws2.py", line 82, in <module>
    start_data_receiver()
  File "data_receiver_ws2.py", line 79, in start_data_receiver
    server.serveforever()
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SimpleWebSocketServer/SimpleWebSocketServer.py", line 704, in serveforever
    super(SimpleSSLWebSocketServer, self).serveforever()
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SimpleWebSocketServer/SimpleWebSocketServer.py", line 678, in serveforever
    self.serveonce()
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SimpleWebSocketServer/SimpleWebSocketServer.py", line 614, in serveonce
    if client.sendq:
AttributeError: type object 'DataWebSocket' has no attribute 'sendq'
```

Comment: Your implementation of `__new__` is messed up. When you call `super().__new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)` you need to return that object as the result. i.e. `__new__(cls, ...)` should return an instance of a `cls`, not the `cls` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__new__` needs to create an instance of `cls` and return it. You are returning `cls` itself. So something like this:

```
def __new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
    instance = super().__new__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
    instance.udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # add udp socket as a class attribute (not instance attribute)
    instance.udp_sock.setblocking(False)
    instance.udp_sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 6666))
    return instance
```

The reason you get an `AttributeError` is that you are then trying to use the `DataWebSocket` type itself (that you returned from the constructor) instead of an instance of it, so the attributes that would have been set in `__init__` are not present.

There is nothing much wrong with your `__init__()` method (except you should be suppressing exceptions: just let the exception bubble up to the top level). `__init__` initialises the object passed to it, it does not return anything. Just call the superclass `__init__` the way you are doing.

`__new__` constructs a new object so it must return it. If the object it returns is an instance of `cls` then Python will call `__init__` automatically. If you return something different (as you are doing here) then Python will not call `__init__` for you as `__init__` for a class may only be called with an instance of that class (or a subclass).

Comment: How I can apply `__init__` method of super class to new class (`instance`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add class attributes

```
class DataWebSocket(WebSocket):
    my_attr = "banana"
```

Every method of your class is technically the same as an attribute.

Comment: Is there different way with `__new__`?

Comment: Yes, and he needs to add `sendq` to his class as an attribute to fix his problem from my understanding

Comment: And what is `sendq` supposed to be? It's not even clear whether `sendq` is supposed to be a class or instance attribute.  Your answer is not very helpful at this point.

Comment: If this doesn't answer the question, I might as well delete it.